# Big Decimal trim to two decimal places

Tags: java

Below code gives me about 14 decimal places. How can i trim it to the 2 decimal place?

```
public class BigDecimalGenerator
     {     public static void main(String[] args)
    
     {  BigDecimal max = new BigDecimal("50.00");   
        BigDecimal min = new BigDecimal("-50.00");  
        BigDecimal range = max.subtract(min);   
        BigDecimal result = min.add(range.multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.random())));  
        System.out.println(result);     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this method on `BigDecimal`

```
setScale(int newScale, int roundingMode)
```

using the desired scale (2) and roundingmode.

Answer (score 1):

Set the rounding mode and scale.

```
BigDecimal max = new BigDecimal("50.00");
BigDecimal min = new BigDecimal("-50.00");
BigDecimal range = max.subtract(min);
BigDecimal result = min
        .add(range.multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.random())));

result = result.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

System.out.println(result);
```

Prints something like.

```
-31.28
```